# Build opencv android ndk project

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I'm trying to build opencv android ndk project. I looked in the samples in the opencv folder and Android.mk there look like that:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on

include ../includeOpenCV.mk
ifeq ("$(wildcard $(OPENCV_MK_PATH))","")
    #try to load OpenCV.mk from default install location
    include $(TOOLCHAIN_PREBUILT_ROOT)/user/share/OpenCV/OpenCV.mk
else
    include $(OPENCV_MK_PATH)
endif

LOCAL_MODULE    := native_sample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

it looks like i need to change the paths to fit my pc but i'm not sure what this part mean:

```
include ../includeOpenCV.mk
ifeq ("$(wildcard $(OPENCV_MK_PATH))","")
    #try to load OpenCV.mk from default install location
    include $(TOOLCHAIN_PREBUILT_ROOT)/user/share/OpenCV/OpenCV.mk
else
    include $(OPENCV_MK_PATH)
endif
```

I have one cpp file in which i used opencv functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the include path to the directory to which you have extracted your opencv-android sdk.

change

```
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on

include ../includeOpenCV.mk
ifeq ("$(wildcard $(OPENCV_MK_PATH))","")
    #try to load OpenCV.mk from default install location
    include $(TOOLCHAIN_PREBUILT_ROOT)/user/share/OpenCV/OpenCV.mk
else
    include $(OPENCV_MK_PATH)
endif
```

to

```
 OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
 OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on

// Location in which you have extracted your opencv-android-sdk 

 include C:\OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk-r2\OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\OpenCV.mk

 // remove this previously existing macro once you have set your absolute path
```